# Win32 API, System Tray Icon disapearing

Tags: c++, winapi, system-tray

I'm currently working on a Win32 application and I want to have an icon in the system task bar. I'm using `Shell_NotifyIcon` to display the icon, and it works well but often the icon disapears without explanation...

In fact, the bug appears the first time I run the code in Visual Studio 2013 after having built the code OR when I run the application from the `.exe` in another directory (I don't have any error like `missing dll` and the application is running, but the icon is not there anymore... ).

The code I use to create the icon:

```
// At the beginning of the file
static NOTIFYICONDATA m_nid ;

// After
m_nid.cbSize = sizeof (m_nid);
m_nid.hWnd = hwnd;
m_nid.uVersion = NOTIFYICON_VERSION_4 ;
static const GUID myGUID =
{0x5CA81ADA, 0xA481, 0x4BA8, {0x8B, 0x70, 0x80, 0x3f, 0x48, 0x67, 0xA1, 0x68}};
m_nid.guidItem = myGUID;

m_nid.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_TIP | NIF_GUID | NIF_MESSAGE ;
m_nid.uCallbackMessage = WM_SYSTEM_TRAY;
StringCchCopy (m_nid.szTip, ARRAYSIZE (m_nid.szTip), NotificationManager::APPLICATION_NAME.c_str ());
m_nid.hIcon = (HICON) LoadImage (NULL, L"icon_v1.ico", IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADFROMFILE);

ShowWindow (m_nid.hWnd, SW_HIDE);
Shell_NotifyIcon (NIM_ADD, &m_nid);
Shell_NotifyIcon (NIM_SETVERSION, &m_nid);
```

**Edit:** I think it's a problem with the `GUID` because in `Release` mode the icon was not showing, but since I changed the `GUID` it's working... But it still not works when I run the program outside Visual Studio...

Comment: It's not being *hidden* is it? (Banished from useful plain sight to the bin with all of the other annoying tray icons)

Comment: Also when developing tray icon software, when it crashes/you stop the debugger, old icons can get left behind. Make sure you do the mouse wiggle over the tray to clear out the ones that didn't get automatically removed.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart No, it is not hidden, and I remove the icon each time I stop the program in debug mode.

Answer (score 6):

There are several possibilities for why a system tray icon disappears.

1. The HWND associated with the icon was destroyed.
2. In modern Windows versions, the icon has been hidden from view by user settings outside of your app's control.
3. Windows Explorer crashed and restarted, but you did not handle the `TaskbarCreated` message to re-add your icon.

**Edit**: Another possibility is that you are simply passing bad input to `Shell_NotifyIcon()` and it is failing with an error that you are ignoring.

Comment: The HWND is still living, for the 2 point I let you see my comment on jalf answer, and for the third point it's very unlinkely because it happens each time I start the program, but I'll check the the `TaskbarCreated` message.

Comment: TaskbarCreated was the answer for me!

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely intended behavior. Windows 7 (and later) is very aggressive about not always displaying notification icons, because they are, and were, heavily abused. Their intend were, as the name implies, to provide notifications, and nothing else.

The API doesn't guarantee that your icon will be visible. It only allows you to register that you would like to make a notification. It is up to the OS to decide whether that notification should be displayed, and for how long.

If you go into Notification Area Icons in the Control Panel, you can see the settings that are applied to each icon. Most likely, yours is set to either "Hide icon and notifications", or "only show notifications".

And no, there is nothing you can do about that, other than asking the user to allow your icon. Once again, the API is for delivering notifications, and if the user doesn't want to see your icon or your notification, the OS respects that.

Comment: The problem is not the Windows 7 behavior for tray icon. My icon is not visible in the `hidden icons` list, and I've set `Show icon and notifications.` for my application in the `Customize` menu.

Answer (score 0):

from the notification documentation on msdn I see this:

```
> Each icon in the notification area can be identified in two ways:
> 
>     The GUID with which the icon is declared in the registry. This is the preferred method on Windows 7 and later.
>     The handle of a window associated with the notification area icon, plus an application-defined icon identifier. This method is used on
> Windows Vista and earlier.
```

here is the link also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx